# stdClass::$plugin in /home/servupgg/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-list-util.php on line 152

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I watch this error when I add a new plugin in my WordPress dashboard. please any expert solve my problem
my site: https://serverproofs.com

I already use the latest version of WordPress.
I use couponis theme.

```
if ( ! $index_key ) {
        /*
         * This is simple. Could at some point wrap array_column()
         * if we knew we had an array of arrays.
         */
        foreach ( $this->output as $key => $value ) {
            if ( is_object( $value ) ) {
//152 line              $newlist[ $key ] = $value->$field;
            } else {
                $newlist[ $key ] = $value[ $field ];
            }
        }

        $this->output = $newlist;

        return $this->output;
    }
```

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$plugin in /home/servupgg/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-list-util.php on line 152

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$plugin in /home/servupgg/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-list-util.php on line 152

Comment: Please see the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14cry83A_l2d3aS1x-HgFZ_FaAL9t8_iT

Answer (score 1):

Try below solutions in sequence, one of them will surely fix the issue.

Solution1: Go To Dashboard -> Update -> On You have the latest version of WordPress, click Re-Install Now.

Solution2: Set debug mode to false in config file define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

Solution3: Remove all transients from db via the Litespeed Cache plugin or any plugin of your choice.

Answer (score -1):

Check your php version. Version 8 doesn't work. Use 7.4.